# Not able to view the Database Diff Report in Azure Devops Build pipeline

Tags: database, azure-devops, redgate, readyroll, red-gate-sql-prompt

I was able to use the Redgate Ready Roll extension in Azure Devops Build and Release Pipeline. Everything was working fine till 8th April,2019. Now, suddenly I am facing below challenges.

- I am not able to view the Database Diff Report in AzureDevops Build Pipeline. On the other hand the Database reports are getting generated and present in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory.`
  I can Download the Same (.html) from publish artifact of build definition and can view the changes.
- When I click on Database Diff Report Tab in Build , I got below message

  > Redgate ReadyRoll is taking longer than expected to load
  > [image]
- Also in the Summary Tab of Build Pipeline, In Database deployment preview I am getting Below Message

  > Redgate ReadyRoll by Redgate Software failed to load
  > [image]
  > Any help will be appreciable.
  > Thanks in Advance.